# I've always gotten this error on my Ubuntu 20.04 bash: python: command not found. Trying to install using apt-get proves that python exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash

On my Ubuntu 20.04, when I try installing python from "apt" it shows that python is installed. However, running: **which python** or **which python3**, returns nothing.

Answer (score -3):

This was how I resolved the error:

```
1) Download the python .tar file from https://www.python.org/downloads/
2) Decompress the downloaded file by doing: tar xfvJ <the downloaded filename> e.g tar xfvJ  Python-3.10.4.tar.xz

3) cd into the decompressed folder: i.e cd Python-3.10.4 (for instance)
4) if you do: ls in this folder, you'd find a file: README.rst
```

This file holds the configuration sequence (procedure), which includes the following:

```
./configure
    make
    make test
    sudo make install
```

run each line as a separate command and restart your machine. That definitely solves the problem. "This will install Python as `python3`"

Comment: That sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: That's how I solved my problem; you should probably read about Jean Fourier Baptiste, when he opposed Lagrange and co.... Tell me what you got.